# Ruby error: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting then or ';' or '\n'

Tags: ruby

I've run across something unexpected with some basic ruby code, and I don't quite understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
irb(main):014:0>  if "x".include? "x" && "y".include? "y"
irb(main):015:1> puts "true"
irb(main):016:1> end
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from /usr/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        2: from /usr/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        1: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
SyntaxError ((irb):14: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting then or ';' or '\n')
....include? "x" && "y".include? "y"
...                              ^
(irb):16: syntax error, unexpected end, expecting end-of-input
irb(main):017:0>
```

But if I use `and` instead of `&&` this works ok.

```
irb(main):011:0>  if "x".include? "x" and "y".include? "y"
irb(main):012:1> puts "true"
irb(main):013:1> end
true
=> nil
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your arguments in parenthesis.

You're confusing the interpreter by leaving them out.

```rb
irb(main):002:0> puts 'true' if "x".include?("x") && "y".include?("y")
true
```

Comment: Yeah, I maintain that one should almost always use parentheses, save for DSL (attr_accessor, belongs_to, etc.)